# Can you help me open py.file

Tags: python

I was using python then I had to uninstall it and after Uninstall I reinstalled it and now I cant open any py file and it comes with choose a default app. I dont know why this happened. Please help me and this can be off topic or so but please help me before you flag this post or whatever. I tried repairing but it didnt help

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall is and reinstalling it again?

Comment: Also you can just manually choose a default app for it...

Comment: Yes i did also wich program should i choose

Comment: What text editor or IDE did you use before/do you want to use?

Answer (score 0):

What OS are you using? Sounds like you don’t have an IDE. You could install PyCharm for example to edit and run your scripts.

Comment: now im trying pycharm and replying you back. I use windows

Comment: it failed please help

Comment: If you have an IDE on your computer, just choose it as the default app for this kind of file...